# Get the last entry in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I display the last entry  in my blade.
I have this request:

```
@foreach(($listContrat = \App\Stagiaire::join('carrieres', 'stagiaires.id', '=',  'carrieres.stagiaire_id')
    ->where('stagiaires.id', $id)
    ->OrderBy('id','desc')
    ->take(1)
    ->get())  
     as $key => $car)
```

I have this error message with this query

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `stagiaires`

Comment: The error is telling you that both `carrieres` and `stagiaires` have `created_at` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks freedomn-m

The solution is:

```
@foreach(($listContrat = \App\Stagiaire::join('carrieres', 'stagiaires.id', 
'=', 'carrieres.stagiaire_id')
                        ->where('stagiaires.id', $id)- 
>OrderBy('carrieres.id','Desc')->take(1)->get())  as $key => $car)
```